# How come Desmos renders $\sqrt{x}^2$ as $y=x$ for $x \ge 0$ and undefined otherwise?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

When I graph the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}^2$ on Desmos, the output is the graph of the piecewise function $f(x)=x$, $x\ge0$; undefined otherwise.

I expected the graph of the absolute value function instead, because I thought that $\sqrt{x}^2 = \sqrt{x^2} = |x|$. Why are they not considered to be equal?

Comment: Because square root of a negative number is not defined on reals. You would need to use an intermediate step with complex numbers to get to your conclusion

Comment: $\sqrt x$ is defined only for real $x \geq 0$.  In $\sqrt{x^2}$, for all real x, $x^2 \geq 0$, hence is defined.

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ has domain restriction built in to it, $x \ge 0$

Comment: It’s definitely not the absolute value function. How do you define $\sqrt{-1}?$ It is either defined as $i,$ the imaginary number, or it is undEfined. So either $\sqrt{-1}^2$ is undefined, or it is $i^2=-1.$ However, $\sqrt{x^2}$ is the absolute value function.

Comment: @user29418 This domain restriction also applies to all $\sqrt[n]{x}$ where $n$ is an even integer > 0? So we could say that $\sqrt{x}^n \neq \sqrt{x^n}$?

Comment: yes: it's not possible to define negative even roots without imaginary numbers

Comment: yes you can say so

Answer (score 1):

I'll add an answer, even though people in the comments have summed it up perfectly.

Negative numbers don't have square roots that are real numbers. This is why the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ has the restriction $x\geq0$. As such, the function $f(x)=(\sqrt{x})^2$ will also have the restriction $x\geq0$.

When it comes to $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2}$, a restriction in the domain is no longer needed because $x^2$ will always be greater than or equal to zero regardless of whether $x$ is positive or negative.